Weight Paint - Unable to change weight painting
I am trying to do Weight Painting for my human model.

Selected armature.
Selected skin.
Went to "Weight Paint" environment.
Selected one of my bones by Alt-left click.
I noticed a lot of weight painting in areas on the palm outside the thumb that aren't supposed to be there. (1.png)
I cleared all the weight painting in the areas that I don't want the paint to be. (2.png)
I moved on to another bone to clear the weights I don't want. (3.png and 4.png)
I returned to the original bone in 1.png and found extra weights there even though I had removed those extra weights earlier. (5.png)

How do I prevent these extra weights from appearing? Thanks in advance.
